# How to make a service method that gets collection of POJOs

Tags: java, cuba-platform

I have such service:

```
public interface FireService {
    void addTags(String sessionId, List<TagCreateRequest> tags);
}
```

Here TagCreateRequest is:

```
@MetaClass(name = "...")
public class TagCreateRequest extends AbstractNotPersistentEntity implements Serializable {

    @MetaProperty(mandatory = true)
    protected TagType type;

    @MetaProperty(mandatory = true)
    protected Double time;

    @MetaProperty
    protected String text;

    public void setType(TagType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public TagType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setTime(Double time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public Double getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

}
```

My problem is when i'm trying to make REST request to method `addTags` like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/rest/v2/services/fire_FireService/addTags
{
    "sessionId": "1417270d-31cb-be3c-e583-4b172b4183a9",
    "tags": [
        {
            "type": "fire",
            "time": 12.333
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "time": 15.12,
            "text": "Test!!!"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting the `EntitySerializationException` that tells me that `MetaClass` for entity is not defined:

```
EntitySerializationException: Cannot deserialize an entity. MetaClass is not defined
```

I tried to look how platform determines the `MetaClass` and found strange thing. If service parameter is `Collection`, then passed `MetaClass` is `null`:

```
@Component("cuba_RestParseUtils")
public class RestParseUtils {
...
    public Object toObject(Class clazz, String value) throws ParseException {
    ...
        if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return entitySerializationAPI.<Entity>entitiesCollectionFromJson(value, null);
        }
    ...
    }
...
}
```

What should i do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You must explicitly specify the type of instances in the collection. Use the *_entityName* field in each *TagCreateRequest* entity:

```json
{
    "sessionId": "1417270d-31cb-be3c-e583-4b172b4183a9",
    "tags": [
        {
            "_entityName": "prj_TagMetaClassName",
            "type": "fire",
            "time": 12.333
        },
       {
            "_entityName": "prj_TagMetaClassName", 
            "type": "text",
            "time": 15.12,
            "text": "Test!!!"
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you could extract generic info from method declaration though

Comment: What if i can't change the json structure?

Comment: I mean, here is already everything needed to deserialize the data. Why i must define additional options?

Comment: You're right, we can implement it. Generic info will be automatically extracted in one of future platform releases. The issue: https://youtrack.cuba-platform.com/issue/PL-8485